# Weaker condition for kernel of morphisms of sheaves being sheaf?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The (pre)sheaves are of abelian groups.

I just want to fact-check an idea of mine.

I was trying to prove that "the kernel of morphisms of sheaves is indeed a sheaf", but I ended up proving that "the presheaf kernel $\ker(\mathscr F \to \mathscr G)$ is a sheaf with $\mathscr F$ being a sheaf and $\mathscr G$ just being a presheaf" by diagram chasing.

Am I wrong here? It does require that both $\mathscr F$ and $\mathscr G$ should be sheaves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you require $\mathscr G$ to satisfy locality axiom.

First if $i: \mathcal A \rightarrow \mathcal B$ be an injective morphism between presheafs and $\mathcal B$ satisfies locality axiom then $\mathcal A$ satisfies locality axiom (if a section $s \in \mathcal A(U)$ zeros for some cover is will zero on the same cover in $\mathcal B$).

Now let $f: \mathcal A \rightarrow \mathcal B$ be a morphism of sheafs.
If you take any compatible collection $s_i \in \mathcal A(U_i)$ such that $f(s_i) = 0$ (so $s_i \in (\ker f)(U)$ ), they glue to some $s \in \mathcal A(\bigcup_i U_i)$. But $f(s) = 0$ locally, so if we assume that locality axiom holds for $\mathcal B$ then we are done.

If you do not assume that $\mathscr G$ is a sheaf then consider the following counterexample: let $X=\{0,1\}$ with discrete topology. Consider a sheaf $\mathcal{A}$ of locally constant functions with values in $\mathbb{Z}$ on $X$. Consider a presheaf $\mathcal B$ given by $\mathcal B(X) = \mathbb{Z}$ and $0$ otherwise. Then a morphism $f: \mathcal A \rightarrow \mathcal B$ given on global section by $f((x, y)) = x + y$ and as a zero morphism everywere else is a sheaf morphism (all squares commute trivially as you will get zero morphisms everywere), but the kernel of this morphism will be the presheaf of constant functions which is not a sheaf.

Comment: Nice job! Thank you very much. I see what is going wrong in my proof and turn out that the locality of $\mathscr G$ is the cure.